# Применение составного свойства при использовании триггеров в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток, ХешКодовцы

Хочу применять триггер на фокус кнопки, при этом изменять границы объекта. Но триггер, как я понял, применяется на одно свойства. Как мне применить целый объект при срабатывании триггера?

Пример того, что хочу применить при срабатывании триггера:

```
<Border.Background>
    <LinearGradientBrush>
        <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="#e7ebf7" Offset="0.0"></GradientStop>
                <GradientStop Color="#cee3ff" Offset="0.8"></GradientStop>
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</Border.Background>
```

Заранее спасибо за Ваши ответы.

Comment: Точно так же: объект вполне может быть значением свойства. По поводу синтаксиса смотрите ответ @petya.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush>
                            <GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                <GradientStopCollection>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#e7ebf7" Offset="0.0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#cee3ff" Offset="0.8"/>
                                </GradientStopCollection>
                            </GradientBrush.GradientStops>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: Я бы ещё положил `LinearGradientBrush` отдельно в ресурсы, всё-таки самостоятельная сущность.